# Method calling itself in a loop

Tags: java, methods

Inside of a test class there is a static method to return a set of all files inside a particular directory.

Because the method is calling itself to loop through files, I instantiated a set `listOfFiles` outside the method to add files I find. This works great the first time I call the method, but the second time I call it, `listOfFiles` gets added up and I can't clear it because of the return statement. Any ideas?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashSet;

class TestClass {
    static HashSet<File> listOfFiles = new HashSet<File>();
    
    //returns all files in the directory as a set
    static HashSet<File> getAllFiles(File file) {
        if(file.isDirectory()) {
            for(File subFiles : file.listFiles()) {
                if(subFiles.isDirectory()) {
                    getAllFiles(subFiles);
                } else {
                    listOfFiles.add(subFiles);              
                    }
            }
        } else {
            listOfFiles.add(file);              
        }

//      listOfFiles.clear();
        return listOfFiles;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass.getAllFiles(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents")).forEach(System.out::println);
        TestClass.getAllFiles(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop")).forEach(System.out::println);
        
    }
}
```

I could probably solve this if I write bunch more methods or manually clear the set every time I call the method, but none of this seems elegant and clean.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a `static` field for that.

Instead create a `HashSet` on the first invocation and pass it into all others.

The simplest way to do this is to have a separate helper method like this:

```
public static Set<File> getAllFiles(File file) {
    Set<File> result = new HashSet<>();
    getAllFilesImpl(file, result);
    return result;
}

private static void getAllFilesImpl(File file, Set<File> result) {
    if(file.isDirectory()) {
        for(File subFile : file.listFiles()) {
            if(subFile.isDirectory()) {
                getAllFilesImpl(subFile, result);
            } else {
                result.add(subFile);              
            }
        }
    } else {
        result.add(file);              
    }
}
```

Note that I also changed the return type of `getAllFiles()` to just `Set<File>` because the concrete implementation class used (`HashSet` in this case) shouldn't matter to the caller. That's called "coding to interfaces". That change isn't necessary for this to work, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
static HashSet<File> getAllFiles(File file) {
    HashSet<File> set = new HashSet<>();
    File[] files = file.listFiles();
    if (files != null) {
        for (File f : files) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                set.addAll(getAllFiles(f));
            } else {
                set.add(f);
            }
        }
    }
    return set;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).